# Javascript - Use local var or this?

Tags: javascript, caching, this, keyword

I am working with prototype methods and here is the scenerio

```
function Foo () {
    this.x = 5;
    this.y = 2;
    this.z = this.addValues();
}
Foo.prototype = {
    addValues:  function (){
        return this.x + this.y; 
    }
}
```

Obviously this is just a simple example; in real project, there will be lot of activities in the 'addValue' function. Is it fine to use 'this' keyword 100s of times or caching this to local variable helps any performance improvements. For example, the below will make any difference?

```
Foo.prototype = {
    addValues:  function (){
        var self = this;
        return self.x + self.y; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The latter is usually only used when you need to save the current context because `this` is about to change.

Comment: `this` is (effectively) a local variable, it is set when the execution context is entered. So using it should have the same performance as a local variable, perhaps faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is the standard way to access `x` and `y`.  You'll get no improvements from caching `this` to a local var—if anything, you're wasting space by declaring `self` in the first place.

The only **possible** risk you'd see is with something like this:

```
var f = new foo();
var stupid = f.addValues;
stupid(); // whoops - this is suddenly the global object, 
          // and your method is broken.
```

Having said that, I don't think you're responsible for people misusing your function, and I wouldn't worry about it.

Also, by convention, functions meant to be used as constructors should start with a capital letter.  Consider renaming `foo` to `Foo`

Comment: Thanks Adam Rackis and everyone for the answers!

Comment: +1, but the `var stupid = f.foo` thing isn't affected one way or the other by the proposed code in the question.

Comment: @nnnnnn - thanks - I meant to say `var stupid = f.addValues;`  which of course would be affected  http://jsfiddle.net/rZemZ/  Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @nnnnnn - I'm sorry, you're right that it's not affected by the *code in question*.  I just wanted to point out one potential, hypothetical, silly possibility just for completeness.

Comment: Completeness is good, except of course when it confuses me, personally. Fortunately I was already aware of the issue you were pointing out, and I agree that it is good for all JS coders to learn how JS's `this` works...

Answer (score 5):

There's probably no meaningful difference between `self.x` and `this.x`.  What *might* make a difference is

```
  var x = this.x, y = this.y;

  // massive amounts of computation involving x and y
```

Such micro-optimizations are probably not worth it unless you're really involved in some cutting-edge game development or something. Get your *algorithms* and *data structures* up to snuff first, and then worry about stuff like this last. You never know when the developers of the JavaScript runtime systems will introduce new optimizations. They can't fix your bad algorithms, but they can dramatically affect micro-optimizations.

Comment: Also, such optimisations might improve performance in some UAs and degrade it in others. e.g. using a decrementing counter in a while loop used to be much faster in some browsers, but deadly slow in others. In more recent browsers, speed is on par with a standard for loop (mostly).

Comment: @RobG yes indeed - things like that are generally not a good idea unless there's a user agent that's absolutely terrible at some particular thing.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the micro-optimization and mentioning that it likely won't make a difference

Comment: @RobG - is that because older browsers were smart enough to "unroll" for loops, but not while loops with decrementing counters?

Comment: @AdamRackis—I have no idea. Javascript is specified in terms of behaviour, not implementation so as long as a UA achieves the correct result, you need to read the source to find out how they do it (or why they exhibit particular characteristics). I'm not up to that!

Answer (score 0):

In this example, assigning `this` to `self` should not make any difference. JavaScript does not assign objects by value, but rather by reference, meaning that `self` and `this` both then point to the same object. You gain nothing by doing so.

```
foo.prototype = {
    addValue:  function (){
       // self and this point to the same object! 
       var self = this;
        return self.x + self.y; 
    }
}
```